# Which is the least in size for .net execution file?

Tags: .net, asp.net

In .net platform .. can anyone give me name of that file?

Comment: What are you asking for? I don't fully understand your question.

Comment: What on earth are you talking about?

Comment: The name of the file is "NOSMOKE.exe". No need to thank me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a console application doing nothing, the exe file is 15 KB. Hope it can help :)

Comment: i bet you I can make one smaller ;)

Answer (score 3):

Creating a class library with no using statements, one namespace, one class, no debug is 4KB.